# Pring log messages grouped by request in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, java.util.logging

I have a Spring Boot application with a very high request rate.

This application do a lot of steps and those steps' log messages become garbled and mixed.

```
[DEBUG] - Done step1 for user A
[DEBUG] - Step 1 for user A took X seconds 
[DEBUG] - Done step1 for user B
[DEBUG] - Step 2 for user A took X seconds 
[DEBUG] - Step 1 for user B took X seconds 
[DEBUG] - Step 2 for user B took X seconds 
[DEBUG] - Step 3 hit special case for user B
[DEBUG] - Step 3 hit special case for user A
[DEBUG] - Total processing time for user A is XXXX
[DEBUG] - Total processing time for user B is XXXX
```

I would like to accumulate log messages and print them at the end for the processing.

Something like:

```
[DEBUG] - Done step1 for user A
[DEBUG] - Step 1 for user A took X seconds 
[DEBUG] - Step 2 for user A took X seconds 
[DEBUG] - Step 3 hit special case for user A
[DEBUG] - Total processing time for user A is XXXX
[DEBUG] - Done step1 for user B
[DEBUG] - Step 1 for user B took X seconds 
[DEBUG] - Step 2 for user B took X seconds 
[DEBUG] - Step 3 hit special case for user B
[DEBUG] - Total processing time for user B is XXXX
```

**Is that possible with spring boot?**

Currently, I'm accumulating all log messages in a StringBuilder, but I have to pass this object around on all calls. This is very cumbersome take a heavy toll on readability.

Comment: Don't pass it around, write a log message manager that runs on its own thread and queues messages in separate queues, one for each request.  You'll need to be able to tell it when a request is done so it can write the queued messages as a block.

Comment: You can also just assign a request id to this request and log it via MDC. At the end, it would only require a simple grep to understand what happened in the request.

Comment: @JimGarrison do you have any reference to point me to? A google search for custom log manager java didn't turn out to anything relevant.